# How can I convert string to decimal with trailing zero(s)

Tags: c#

Suppose that we have `stringvalue=125.32600` when it convert to decimal value with this code

```
decimal d;
decimal.tryparse(stringvalue,out d)
```

d value is 125.326
how can I do this convert with final result 125.32600

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot because `125.32600` is equal to `125.326`. In this case however I guess that you want to print it out with specific format, which can be done like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("f5"));
```

Read [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

**UPDATE**

Extension method:

```
public string Format(this decimal source, int precision)
{
    if (precision < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Precision must be a non negative integer");
    }

    return source.ToString("f" + precision);
}
```

which can be used like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(d.Format(5));
```

Comment: yeh, exactly. but number of trailing zero(s) depends on user define setting. I Think I have to store decimal point numbers as a option

Comment: `f5` in this case means 5 numbers after decimal point. If you replace it with `f3` then it will show only 3 digits after decimal point.

Comment: So you can have `precision` variable and format your value as you wish.

Comment: @walkhard: because `"f5"` only works with that specific value; no attempt made to provide a generic solution. (btw. also turns out your answer suffers from the same flaw as mine :))

Comment: @ErikAllik No such thing was requested, besides OP can easily rewrite it as needed, but since you've mentioned it I've updated my answer with generic solution.

Comment: @walkhard: I know it wasn't requested, but in my experience, it's hardly ever too useful to anybody to get the solution for just a special-case.

Comment: @walkhard: OK, seeing your edit, I think we interpreted the question completely differently—I saw the `stringvalue = "125..."` part as core to the question.

Comment: @ErikAllik Well you've got a good point, though in my experience it's (sometimes) good to give people directions so they can try and find their own way of doing things instead of giving out full solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works as written (as long as the decimal separator matches your culture):

```
decimal d;
decimal.TryParse("125.32600", NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d);
s = d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // 125.32600
```

`Decimal` already remembers how many trailing zeros it has. This is caused by `decimal` representing numbers in non-normalized form, with an integer mantissa and an exponent representing the number of decimal digits. e.g. `125.32600` is represented as `12532600 * 10^-5`

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: You can't, at least not like that.

**EDIT:** correction: `decimal` already works like that; but you'll still find below a useful way to store your decimals in a DB.

Why? Because that's not how decimals are stored in memory.

Solution: if you need to keep the trailing zeros, just remember the precision explicitly in a separate field (of a class you should create for this purpose); or store the decimals in string form and only convert to `decimal` as needed.

```
string strValue = "125.32600";
int precision = strValue.Length - 1;  // only the "12332600" part
decimal value = Decimal.Parse(strValue);
```

stores `8` in `precision` and `125.326` in `value`.

To get back the original form:

```
int afterPt = precision - ((int) value).ToString().Length;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("f" + afterPt));
```

prints

```
125.32600
```

**P.S.** you have to be aware of floating point binary representation issues though, so stuff like `4.05` might be stored as e.g. `4.049999999999999999`, so if you need to guarantee this won't happen, use an algorithm that bypasses `decimal` altogether and uses only integers for storage and computation.

```
string strValue = "125.32600";

// parse and store
int value = int.Parse(strValue.Replace(".", ""));
int periodIx = strValue.IndexOf(".");

// get back the original representation
string str = value.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(0, periodIx) + "." + str.Substring(periodIx, str.Length - periodIx));
```

**NOTE:** Make sure to use `,` instead of `.` in locales that need it.

Comment: Thank for your response. but I want store user input value with trailing zero(s) in database, what is your solution?

Comment: Store the string, or store a pair of values: precision and value where `precision` stores the number of significant decimal places and `value` is a normal decimal.

Comment: @user2377017: I've amended my answer with the necessary details.

Comment: Your answer would be true for `double`, but it's wrong for decimal in two ways: 1) stuff `4.05m` is exactly representable as `decimal` 2) decimal doesn't require normalization, it can distinguish `1.0` and `1.00`.

Comment: OK, but he still needs to store it in the database.

Comment: @ErikAllik The OP didn't mention any database.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: but he did in the first comment to this answer.

Comment: Then it still depends on the database, so this wouldn't be a C# question anymore.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: it doesn't hurt either to help the OP a bit more; besides, with at least some databases he would need to algorithm in C# to do the conversion both ways.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is `count` the `zeroes` in `string` and then store them in separate DB field. When you want the result with `zeroes` just concatenate the same no. of zeroes into `decimal number string`.

ex.

```
string p="123.456000";
int zeroes=p.Split('0').Length - 1; // guess
decimal value = Decimal.Parse(p); //without zeroes
string valWithZero=value.toString().padRight(zeroes,'0'); //with zeroes
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have the zeros in the database you could save it as a string, preformatted, but that would be very inefficient.

What is the problem you try to solve by this, there might be a better solution?